# Error al llamar al reporte padre de Jasper con Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, jasper-reports

Tengo un problema, genere un reporte en Jasper que tiene subreportes, haciendo las pruebas en Jasper funciona perfectamente, pero, cuando llamo al reporte Padre desde Laravel me da error, si alguien podria guiarme por favor.

```
public function pdf($ofc_cod){
  $input = public_path() . '/reports/prueb.jasper';
  $output = public_path() . '/reports/' . time() . '_Valores';

  $options = [
      'format' => ['pdf'],
      'locale' => 'es',
      'params' => ['test' => $ofc_cod],
      'db_connection' => [
          'driver' => 'postgres',
          'username' => '',
          'password' => '',
          'host' => '',
          'database' => '',
          'port' => '5432'
      ]
  ];
  $jasper = new PHPJasper;
  $jasper->process(
      $input,
      $output,
      $options
  )->execute();
  $file = $output . '.pdf';
  $path = $file;
  if (!file_exists($file)) {
      abort(404);
  }
  $file = file_get_contents($file);
  unlink($path);
  return response($file, 200)
      ->header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
      ->header('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename="cliente.pdf"');
  return view('oficinas.index');
```

POR SEGURIDAD QUITE LA CONFIGURACION DE MI CONEXIONCON MI DB